# Creating sequence of dates as new column in dataframe R

Tags: r, date, sequence, seq

I have been struggling with a simple task (I guess).

I have a dataset containing two columns with start and end date. I want to extract all the months between start and end date, and list them all together in a new column of the dataframe. The next step would be to create dummies for each month listed in that column.

My input data look like this:

```
Lon      Lat      Year    Start_date     End_date    

70.25    40.25    2000    10/01/2009     04/30/2010  

70.75    40.25    2000    05/01/2010     08/30/2010   

71.00    40.25    2000    07/07/2010     11/30/2010
```

This is what I would like to obtain:

```
Lon       Lat    Year     start_date  end_date      Sequence

70.25    40.25    2000    10/01/2009   04/30/2010   10,11,12,1,2,3,4

70.75    40.25    2000    05/01/2010   08/30/2010   5,6,7,8

71.00    40.25    2000    07/01/2010   11/30/2010   7,8,9,10,11
```

Where the last column contains a list of all the months (as number) between start_date and end_date.

This is my tentative code.

```
sequence <- Map(seq.dates, start_date, end_date, by = "months", format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

The code works fine and gives me a list with all the months from start to end date, which is what I was aiming at. However, I am not able to cope with the list then, as I do not find any good way to extract the values of the list into a new column of the dataframe, while keeping the structure (the levels). I have tried almost any suggested in stackoverflaw on how to extract values from the list, and nothing works.
So, I want to start over and change perspective.

Is there any other way to redesign the function above in a way to produce a new column attached to my data, or a vector? AND NOT A LIST? Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, what you showed as the output you want looks like a list. So if not a list, what are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly clear about your expected output but if you want to create dummies for each month one way with `tidyverse` would be to extract month start and end dates, create a dummy column and get the data in wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("date")), as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y") %>%
  mutate(month = map2(Start_date, End_date,
                     ~as.integer(format(seq(.x, .y, by = "month"), "%m")))) %>%
  unnest(cols = month) %>%
  mutate(temp = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = month, values_from = temp, 
             values_fill = list(temp = 0)) %>%
  select(names(df), as.character(1:12))

# A tibble: 3 x 17
#    Lon   Lat  Year Start_date End_date     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  70.2  40.2  2000 2009-10-01 2010-04-30     1     1     1     1     0
#2  70.8  40.2  2000 2010-05-01 2010-08-30     0     0     0     0     1
#3  71    40.2  2000 2010-07-07 2010-11-30     0     0     0     0     0
# … with 7 more variables: `6` <dbl>, `7` <dbl>, `8` <dbl>, `9` <dbl>,
#   `10` <dbl>, `11` <dbl>, `12` <dbl>
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Lon = c(70.25, 70.75, 71), Lat = c(40.25, 40.25, 
40.25), Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L), Start_date = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("05/01/2010", "07/07/2010", "10/01/2009"), class = "factor"), 
End_date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("04/30/2010", "08/30/2010", 
"11/30/2010"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Comment: I have a similar problem here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679046/as-posixct-is-taking-inclusive-values-for-time-providing-incorrect-output]. Could you help ?

Comment: @Belle Looks like you deleted the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `spread` from `tidyr` which would also work if the `tidyr` version is not the current one

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(ends_with("date")), as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y") %>%
   mutate(month = map2(Start_date, End_date,
                      ~as.integer(format(seq(.x, .y, by = "month"), "%m")))) %>%
   unnest(cols = month) %>%
   mutate(temp = 1) %>% 
   spread(month, temp, fill = 0)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Lon = c(70.25, 70.75, 71), Lat = c(40.25, 40.25, 
40.25), Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L), Start_date = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("05/01/2010", "07/07/2010", "10/01/2009"), class = "factor"), 
End_date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("04/30/2010", "08/30/2010", 
"11/30/2010"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```